# Giving files copied to directory the same permissions as the directory

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, file-permissions

I am using LAMP Apache version 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.6.

I have created a directory /var/www/dropbox which has permissions rwxrwsr-x.  I have made the group www-OtagoHarbour the owner where www-OtagoHarbour was created using

```
sudo groupadd www-OtagoHarbour
sudo usermod -G www-OtagoHarbour apache
sudo usermod -G www-OtagoHarbour OtagoHarbour
```

I have given apache ownership of the directory using

```
sudo chown apache /var/www/dropbox
```

and the group access using

```
sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www/dropbox
sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+r /var/www/dropbox
sudo chmod -R g+r /var/www
```

I upload files to that folder using the following html call.

```
<form action="http://whatever.com/uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
<input type="hidden" id="LoggedIn" name="LoggedIn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="setName" name="setName" value="<?php echo $setName ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] ?>">
</form>
```

uploadFiles.php copies the uploaded files into /var/www/dropbox.  Unfortunately, the permissions of the uploaded files are -rw-r--r-- whereas I would like them to be -rw-rw-r--.  I tried

```
sudo find /var/www/dropbox -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
```

and rebooted the computer but the uploaded files still have permission -rw-r--r--.  I know I can change the permissions using

```
sudo chmod g+w fileName
```

but I would like this to be done automatically since I have code that processes the files and sends them elsewhere.

Comment: Just a side note, files shouldn't be marked executable unless they specifically need to be executable.  Hint: very few files need to be executable.  Maybe I'm misreading that `find` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could set the default permissions, for new files created in the folder to -rw-rw----. using

```
setfacl -dm u::rw,g::rw,o::--- /var/www/dropbox
```

I then create a "placeholder" file in /var/www/dropbox  using

```
echo "junk" >/var/www/dropbox/file.name
```

If I then copy a file, file.name, into /var/www/dropbox, it assumes the permissions of the file it is overwriting.